# Update fields dynamically in postgres without using the || operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I have this function that updates a table accordingly. I have used the pipe (||) operator already to pick the new values or retain the old ones if nothing was supplied in the request body for that field but I realized this method may not be maintainable if the columns are much. Hence, is there a way one can just extract only the fields that are supplied into the request body and then inject them into their respective columns without using the pipe (||)?

```
 static async updateProduct(req, res) {
        const { id } = req.authData.payload;
        const {
          description, category, imageurl, quantity, unitPrice
        } = req.body;


        try {
          const { rows } = await db.query(queryProductAdmin, [req.params.productId, id]);
          if(!rows[0]) {
            return res.status(404).json({
              status: 'Fail',
              message: 'The product is not available'
            });
          }
          **/** Instead of using the pipe, how can something like this be achieved?
            .update(req.body, { fields: Object.keys(req.body) })*/**
          const values = [
            description || rows[0].description,
            category || rows[0].category,
            imageurl || rows[0].imageurl,
            quantity || rows[0].quantity,
            unitPrice || rows[0].unitPrice,
            req.params.productId,
            id
            ];

            const response = await db.query(updateProductQuery, values);
            const updatedProduct = response.rows[0];
            return res.status(200).json({
              message: 'Update was successful',
              updatedProduct
            });

        } catch(error) {
          const { message } = error;
          return res.status(500).json({
            status: 'Fail',
            message
          });
        }
```

**N.B: The code is working fine. I just need ideas on how to update dynamically.**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
const values = ['description', 'category', 'imageurl', 'unitPrice']
  .map(v => req.body[v] || rows[0][v])
  .push(req.params.productId, id)
```

To go a bit further you could get the table fields using postgres API and map those instead depending on whether or not you are showing all the fields in the query array or not

Comment: I have not tried it but will try it out later. I accepted it hoping it will be correct. Thank you.

Comment: pls what do you mean by Postgres API, I am using the node-pg library?

Comment: Right...I don't know it at all but it would have methods to get table fields

Comment: I don't think it does but you can also check it out here [link](https://node-postgres.com/)

Comment: Would be a SELECT statement